# Is there any ajax slider which support facebook application

Tags: facebook

I am developing a facebook application. Is there any ajax slider which support facebook application.

Comment: An ajax slider which supports facebook applications? Can you elaborate? I find it hard to get the relation between the two.

Comment: a fb ajax slider. because normal ajax won't work in facebook application.

Comment: This is a slider: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider_(computing). Are you sure it is the term you meant? Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: i mean slider like this http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/mosaic-slideshow-jquery-css/

Comment: You want a slideshow and don't know how to access the images? I still don't know how you want to combine this with actual applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

> We are in the process of deprecating
>   FBML. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please
>   implement your application using HTML,
>   JavaScript and CSS. You can use our
>   JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to
>   embedded many of the same social
>   features available in FBML. While
>   there is still functionality that we
>   have not ported over yet, we are no
>   longer adding new features to FBML.

My point is, if you want to use a fancy jQuery slideshow, you can use it, and even more, according to facebook, you should use it, and start forgetting fbml and fbjs.